# Should an assert be used to fix an IDE warning?

Tags: java, refactoring, assert

To be more concise, which one of these methods should I use?

For context, the warning (marked in yellow in the image below) says that the lore variable might be null, although I handle it (marked in blue).

[image]

These are the solutions I came up with:

1. The "assert so that he shuts up": [image]
2. The "remove that method and use another": [image]
3. The "unnecessary if": [image]

I used the second option, just assert it, but I know that I shouldn't use assertion for such unimportant stuff.

Comment: Short answer: Use the if statement. Long answer: see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should an assert be used to fix an IDE warning?

No it shouldn't.  The reason is that the `assert` is not guaranteed to prevent the NPE ... should the value be `null` at runtime.  Why?  Because the execution of `assert` statements is conditional on the JVM being run with an appropriate `-ea` option.  The default is that assertion checking is off.

And besides, I suspect that an `assert` wouldn't suppress the warning anyway, at least for *some* IDEs and bug checkers.

---

As @Aarav [writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74891576/139985) adding a possibly redundant `if` test for `null` is the best solution.  Using a temporary variable is a good idea too, especially if it avoids a *costly* extra method call.

There is no need to worry that the redundant test will have a runtime overhead.  The JIT compiler is good at optimizing out redundant `null` checks.  For example:

```
if (obj != null) {
    obj.someMethod();
}
```

In addition to the explicit `null` test, there is a 2nd implicit test for null when you call `someMethod` on `obj`.  But the JIT compiler will remove the 2nd test because it "knows" that it has already checked that `obj` is not `null`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the accurate answer! I also changed the slang expression in favour of "remove". Some time ago I made a post about assert statements and found out that an assert can also be used to aid developers who are reading a private method to understand it better, as the official Oracle documentation says, am I wrong? I really want to get java asserts right as I'm getting extremely different answers from different sources. Again, thanks!

Comment: Opinions differ on `assert` in Java, but (AFAIK) most Java programmers avoid them in production code; see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/137158.  (And some sources are unreliable or uninformed.  I am thinking of some of the Java tutorials that show up in search results.)

Answer (score 0):

You should never be concerned about a yellow IDE warning, but IF it does happen to matter, I would use option 3. Option 1 will have an unnecessary assert, option 2 will throw your plans as a coder away.

I would like to say it like this: If the IDE doesn't understand your code, add the if statement. It not only makes your code a lot easier to read, but also makes it as a precaution, where if you ever change your code it will be unaffected.

Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answers here, but just wanted to point out that, to me, the logic of that block is completely backwards. So instead, what I'd do would be to rewrite the whole block so that it flows more naturally.

```
private static boolean sendLore( Player player, ItemStack mainHandItem )
{   if  ( mainHandItem.getItemMeta().hasLore() )
    {   player.sendMessage( ChatColor.GREEN + "The lore is: " );
        for ( Component loreItem : mainHandItem.getItemMeta().lore() )
        {   var Message = Component
                          .text( ChatColor.GRAY + String.valueOf( i + 1 ) + ") " + ChatColor.RESET )
                          .append( lineMessage( loreItem ) );
            player.sendMessage( Message );
        }
        return true;
    }
    else
    {   player.sendMessage( ChatColor.RED + "This item doesn't have a lore." );
        return false;
    }
}
```

Presumably this would also make the warning go away.